# Does pages.github.com support directory names with a preceeding . (dot)?

Tags: github-pages, jacoco

I am using a Maven plugin (jacoco-maven-plugin) which generates a site report whose images and css files are in a folder with a preceeding . (dot) in the name.  For example: /site/jacoco/.resources/report.css

When I publish this to my pages.github.com site (using site-maven-plugin), everything is there in my special Github branch (gh-pages).

However, I'm getting 404's when trying to access resources that are in folders with a preceding . (dot) in the folder name.

A simplified example:
https://github.com/justinhrobbins/FlashCards_App/blob/gh-pages/test/.resources/index.html

When I try to access this in my browser i get a 404:
http://justinhrobbins.github.io/FlashCards_App/test/.resources/index.html

However, if I remove the . (dot) from the folder name it works fine:
https://github.com/justinhrobbins/FlashCards_App/blob/gh-pages/test/resources/index.html
http://justinhrobbins.github.io/FlashCards_App/test/resources/index.html

So I'm assuming pages.github.com doesn't support preceeding dot in the folder name (and Googling shows using a preceeding dot may not be a recommended practice anyway) but would appreciate confirmation.

Edit: FYI - when i publish similar to Tomcat it works even with folders with preceeding dot in name

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think this is related to pages.github.com's support for Jekyll.

I am now able to get my page.github.com to work with directory names that include a preceding dot (.)

The solution was to add a .nojekyll file in the root of my gh-pages branch.

The following resources helped me solve the issue:

- [Publishing a Maven site having jacoco reports at Github's gh-pages](http://illegalstateexception.blogspot.com/2013/01/publishing-maven-site-having-jacoco.html)
- [Bypassing Jekyll on GitHub Pages](https://github.com/blog/572-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages)

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this! I was about to throw my computer out the window when I found your...umh, more constructive...answer here!

Answer (score 4):

[As mentioned here](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/7917) you can also configure this with Jekyll itself. Whitelist files/directories by adding them to `_config.yml` in the root directory.

```yaml
include:
  - .my-hidden-folder
```