# hugo, github pages, and tags starting with period

Tags: github-pages, hugo

I'v got a site generated with hugo. One of my blog's tags is ".net", and as such, the corresponding generated folder is .net. This exists on disk, and shows up fine with hugo serve. When I push the site to github to show via github pages, mysite.com/tags/.net results in a 404. /tags/foo works fine. I tried adding a .nojekyll file in the root, and in the docs folder (I'm using a docs folder in the main branch), but no joy. Any idea how I can get github pages to serve the .net folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does pages.github.com support directory names with a preceeding . (dot)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20893913/does-pages-github-com-support-directory-names-with-a-preceeding-dot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the linked post above (which this is kind of a duplicate of), with the following things to note:

- I added .nojekyll to my site root, and to docs/ . I don't know which one's fixing the issue.
- The fix works for folders and files beginning with ., _, etc.
- I'd tried this previously. However, it takes a little time before the github site updates. When I tried this before, I probably didn't wait long enough for the change to kick in.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in Hugo, fixed in `v0.20`.