# How can one get github pages to serve dot files like RFC5785's /.well-known/?

Tags: github-pages, hidden-files, rfc5785, security.txt

I've got a documentation website populated from the Github master branch for my documentation project.

I'd like `https://`*mydomain*`/.well-known/security.txt` to serve the file under `tree/master/.well-known/security.txt` per [securitytxt.org](https://securitytxt.org/) which says

> security.txt defines a standard to help organizations define the process for security researchers to disclose security vulnerabilities securely.
>
> For websites, the security.txt file should be placed under the `/.well-known/` path (`/.well-known/security.txt`) [[RFC5785](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5785)]. It can also be placed in the root directory (`/security.txt`) of a website, especially if the `/.well-known/` directory cannot be used for technical reasons, or simply as a fallback.

The problem I'm seeing is that `.well-known` seems to be ignored by Github pages presumably because it's a hidden file per POSIX file conventions.  Is this configurable?

I could use the fallback quoted above, but I'd rather follow the [RFC5785](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5785) if possible.

For reference, the project I'm currently concerned about is https://github.com/temper-lang/docs and I expect the security.txt to show up at https://temperlang.dev/.well-known/security.txt but get a 404.

Below is a screenshot of my Github pages config:

[image: Github pages config]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It may not be a solution for you if your site is using Jekyll, but in my case I was able to enable serving of files beginning with a dot by creating a `.nojekyll` file in the root of the Github pages repository.

I found this by doing a few more searches on Stackoverflow. Credit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20910276/26219).

Comment: Thanks.  I had no idea that Jekyll was involved in filtering content.

Comment: I can verify that this solved the problem for me.  Thanks much.

Comment: I'm here for the same question too. Adding `.nojekyll` solves my problem. Good Q&A