# Github Pages not pushing site beginning with a

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I had to add a `.fol-der/file.txt` file to my github pages repo for verification.

Now, almost a day after I created it, it can't be accessed by `username.github.io/.fol-der/file.txt`. I can access other files such as `username.github.io/js/file.js`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20893913/does-pages-github-com-support-directory-names-with-a-preceeding-dot)